# How to get history trades of last 10 days from Bittrex using Bittrex API?

Tags: api, trading, bittrex

I want to know how to programmatically get history of trades for period - last 10 days from Bittrex? I saw bittrex API, but using function getmarkethistory I can get only last 200 trades items. But I need to calculate volume buy and volume sell separately for last 10 days and I can't find functions in bittrex API that can help me do this. I saw coinmarketcap.com and bitcoinwisdom API, but I didn't find any solution for this task. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean your own trade history, or trade history for a specific cryptocurrency?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do the same, and as far as I know it is not possible. The best solution may be to start today, and in 10 days you will have 10 days worth of trades :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the market history using "GetTicks" from the v2 API (warning: v2 is still in development so the only [documentation](https://github.com/thebotguys/golang-bittrex-api/wiki/Bittrex-API-Reference-(Unofficial)) that exists is unofficial).

```
import requests
import time
nonce = time.time()
r = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName="BTC-ETH&tickInterval="day")
print(r.json()["result"][0]) # data for 2015-08-14
print(r.json()["result"][-1]) # gives today's data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly from the Bittrex API. You can get raw trades from an API like [Cluedex](https://www.cluedex.com/api). They also offer OHLCV data if you don't want to calculate that yourself.